# How to split xml tag variable and display with php

Tags: php, xml

i get this xml after call to external API that i would like to display all parts of! The first 4 (id, description, minRepeatInterval and active) do i know how to display. I'm using:

```
        $xmlEvents = $response->getBody();
    $xmldata = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlEvents);



    foreach($xmldata->event as $eventData) {

        $eventID = trim($eventData['id']);
        $description = trim($eventData['description']);
        $minRepeatInterval = trim($eventData['minRepeatInterval']);
        $active = trim($eventData['active']);
```

It's the rest i'm having trouble with, how du i display variables inside trigger and action tag onto my php site?

```
<event>
<id>17730</id>
<description>lyset</description>
<minRepeatInterval>1800</minRepeatInterval>
<active>1</active>
<trigger method="1" deviceId="294445" id="18459" type="device" clientId="74144" />
<trigger minute="0" hour="9" id="18721" type="time" clientId="74144" />
<trigger method="1" deviceId="291896" id="19300" type="device" clientId="74144" />
<condition fromHour="7" fromMinute="0" toHour="23" toMinute="0" id="10361" type="time" group="8189" />
<action deviceId="291967" method="1" repeats="3" id="20846" type="device" delay="1" delayPolicy="restart" />
```

Do anyone have have the answer?
Andreas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

these are attributes, and this is one way to access them:

```
echo $xml->trigger[0]['type'];
```

Output:

```
device
```

`trigger[0]` is to select the 1st `<trigger />`, the attribute is selected like an associative array.

read the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php

see it in action: https://eval.in/88785

Answer (score 0):

If that's how your XML begins, you should not iterate event element. Try to use $xmldata->children() instead, in foreach.

Check example here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php